SQLRPGLE delete statment
I'm using a sqlrpgle to insert rows from table A into table B, then I'm deleting rows from table A using another query. At the end, I'd like to retrieve the number of rows deleted following the execution of my query, so that I can display it to the users on the screen.
How can I retrieve this information?
Is there a sqlcod that returns the number of lines deleted?

Look into Get Diagnostics sql statement - this page has examples https://www.rpgpgm.com/2015/04/getting-number-of-rows-affected-by-sql.html
